# How to write a generic FreeAll for TList<T>

Tags: delphi, generics

What is the best way to write a FreeAll function that will take a generic `TList<T>` and free each of the elements of the list?

It makes sense that `TList<T>.FreeAll` does not exist because it would not make sense if the  generic type was a Record or String. Nevertheless it would be very handy if there was some way to achieve the FreeAll functionality if the generic type was an object.

My simple attempt does not compile...

```
TTest1 = Class

End;

Procedure FreeAll(List : TList<TObject>);
Var
    I : Integer;
Begin
    For I := 0 To List.Count - 1 Do
        List[I].Free;
End;


Procedure Main;
Var
    List : TList<TTest1>;
    I : Integer;
Begin
    List := TList<TTest1>.Create;
    List.Add(TTest1.Create);
    List.Add(TTest1.Create);
    List.Free;

    FreeAll(List);

    List.Free;
End;
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `TObjectList`? When its `OwnsObjects` property is set, it will automatically free objects when they're removed from the list (by calling any of `Delete`, `Clear`, or `Free`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your sample solution doesn't work is invariance of instantiated generic types' subtyping relationship with respect to type arguments' subtyping relationship: the fact that the type arguments in your example (`TTest1` and `TObject`) have an inheritance relationship doesn't mean that instantiated types `TList<TTest1>` and `TList<TObject>` have an inheritance relationship. It's easy to see why this is so; consider a value of type `TList<TCat>` that was assignable to a location `b` of type `TList<TAnimal>`; it would then be logically OK to insert a value of type `TDog` into the list referred to by `b`, even though its runtime type is `TList<TCat>`, which shouldn't let `TDog` in.

However, the method you want to write is possible:

```
type
  TObj = class
    procedure FreeAll<T: class>(AList: TList<T>);
  end;

procedure TObj.FreeAll<T>(AList: TList<T>);
var
  x: T;
begin
  for x in AList do
    x.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 10):

In the same Generics.collections.pas unit you have TObjectList, which property OwnsObjects is maybe what you're looking for (for example set OwnsObject to true, call the Clear method and all listed objects are properly freed).

Or you can write your own TList (or maybe TObjectList) descendant where you may add this as a method.

Comment: thanks! Its interesting that the declaration of the TObjectList specifies that the generic type is a class and so T.Free calls are allowed